# Javascript hex number interpolation between several numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a "characters remaining" type counter for a site of mine, and am trying to get smooth color transitions.

How would I go about creating a function to obtain the hex value for a color if I pass the maximum number (in this case 300) and the current char count assuming the pattern is green, yellow, orange, red?

This is in Javascript. Here is what I have so far:

```
function commentcounter(val) {
max = 300;
if(val >= max){
    color = '#FF0000';
}else if(val > (max / 2)){
    color = '#FF9900';
}else{
    color = '#00FF00';
}
display = '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + val + '/' + max + '</span>';
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = display;
}
```

As you can see, this doesn't really interpolate, just goes from green to orange to red.

Comment: [`font` elements?](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT)

Comment: Nice. I'm a bit of a purist, as you might know already by now. ;)

Comment: Hey, switching out deprecated tags is fine by me xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"rgb("+Math.round(Math.min((((chars+(max/2))*2/max)-1)*255,255))+","+Math.round(Math.min(((chars*-2/max)+2)*255,255))+",0)";`

Answer (score 5):

You need to interpolate each color component individually from 0 to 255 (or vice-versa).
This will be much easier if you use `color: rgb(0, 255, 0)`.

Comment: It is unless you are still using IE4. [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: And split up into 3 sections instead of 2: interpolate between green & yellow if 0 < val <= 100; between yellow & orange if 100 < val <= 200, and between orange & red if 200 < val < 300.

Answer (score 0):

This worked better than rgb() for me:

```
var pct = val / max;
var h = pct * 120;
var newColor = 'hsl(' + h + ', 80%, 50%)';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehUHp/